# Call Activity method from Custom view

Tags: android

How to call an activity method from custom view?

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener(v -> ((MyActivity) mContext).onClick(v));
    }
}
```

This works fine as I know that `View` is generated from `MyActivity`.

Is there any way to know which activity has created this `CustomView`? Something like `getActivity().onClick(v)`

Comment: So you tried like : `((MyActivity) mContext).onClick(v)` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, but when I create CustomView from SecondActivity, it requires ((SecondActivity) mContext).onClick(v). I want it to be generic.

Comment: Try using `interface` as CommonsWare said!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what all existing widgets do: accept a callback. So:

Step #1: Define some sort of callback or listener interface.

Step #2: Add `set...()` on the widget to accept an instance of that interface, holding onto it in a field

Step #3: Have the activity, fragment, or whatever call that `set...()` method

Step #4: Have the view call the callback (if one was supplied) when the event occurs

You can see this pattern implemented for things like `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it that way. I thought maybe there is other way, as view knows what is its parent, but it can't be generic... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Said: In Android Jetpack app development, most UI work is managed by fragments, not activities. They might even be configured via data binding expressions. That puts even more emphasis on using callbacks rather than the approach that you were trying, as it is very unlikely that you want the activity to be the one to handle the event.